# HibernateValidator ignored in SpringMVC Tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator, spring-test-mvc, spring-validator

I am trying to use HibernateValidator in SpringMVC tests, but I can't get it to work.
I added it to classpath along with el and validation api deps. In WebMvcConfigurerAdapter overrided getValidator:

```
@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();             
    validatorFactoryBean.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
    return validatorFactoryBean;
}
```

Binding result just doesn't have errors that should be produced by hibernate validator, and DTO has null values. 
However javax validation annotations works.

What I should to do to make hibernate validator work in 
spring mvc tests (with junit runner)?

**UPDATE:**

Here is how my test looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class, WebConfig.class})
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void RegisterUser_ValidData_UserRegistered() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        UserRegistrationDTO dto = new UserRegistrationDTO();
        String payload = mapper.writeValueAsString(dto);

        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post(URI.create("/users/register"))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(payload);

        this.mockMvc.perform(request).andDo...
    }
}
```

*Dependencies:*

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

*Controller:*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "users", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity register(@Valid @RequestBody UserRegistrationDTO registration) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("registered");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to override that method. Post your test as well.

Comment: I would also post the dependencies you are using

Comment: I have provided test and deps.

Comment: Please post the code for the controller that handles requests to `/users/register`.

Comment: That is real controller i have currently)

Comment: Validation errors handled via ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and @ControllerAdvice. But that is working, so no need to provide here.